# ERROR 000210: Cannot create output

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000210

I am currently creating a script for ArcMap that will create a file geodatabase and then two feature class datasets to store feature classes that the script also outputs. At the moment, I can get the script to create the file geodatabase and save the outputs into it. However, if I try and alter the script to save the feature classes into the created feature datasets, I get the "ERROR 000210: Cannot create output".

Is this because the feature datasets are locked and therefore the feature classes cannot be outputted to them?

I am bit flummoxed in what the issue could be. I have copied a snippet below.

```
#This is the snippet. Certain aspects of the script are set by the user as parameters.
#The entire script is encased within a try statement hence the indention. 

    # create the gdb
    ztv_path = os.path.join(GISFolder, "Databases") # location of the geodatabase. The GISFolder is a parameter that is inputted
    ztv_name = "ZTV" # name of the geodatabase

    # Execute Creategdb
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(ztv_path, ztv_name)
    ztvgdb = os.path.join(GISFolder, "Databases", "ZTV.gdb")
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Set the link to the ZTV gdb and then create the feature datasets#
    dataset_outpath = os.path.join (GISFolder,"Databases","ZTV.gdb") # location of the geodatabase to create the datasets in
    temp_name = "ZTV_Temp" #name for the temp dataset
    output_name = "ZTV_Output" #name for the output dataset

    # Execute Createfeaturedataset
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management (dataset_outpath,temp_name,bng)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management (dataset_outpath,output_name,bng)

    ztvOutput = os.path.join(ztvgdb, "ZTV_Ouputs")
    ztvTemp = os.path.join(ztvgdb, "ZTV_Temps")

    # create the study area for the script.
    # This is the part where the script fails and I recieve the Error
    searchArea = os.path.join(ztvgdb,ztvTemp, "studyArea")
    # Buffer...
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inLocation, searchArea, "1000 Meters", "", "", "ALL")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(searchArea, "searchArea_lyr")
```

Comment: Does you path have a number or dot involved? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422311/arcpy-traceback-error-000210-cannot-create-output

Comment: I don't think your [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4313/115) fully qualifies as one.  Have you tried running yours exactly as presented?